# How to verify if max value of a column corresponds to the max value from another column group by a third column

Tags: sql

I have  a table

```
Token | Acct_No | Customer_ID |
|:----|:-------:|-----:|
10 | 1 | ABC
7 | 2 | ABC
6 | 3 | ABC
12 | 4 | ABC
11 | 1 | ABC
8 | 1 | ABC
15| 4 | ABC
16 | 3 | ABC
10 | 2 | CDA
```

I want to know if there are any rows where max(token) for max(acct_no) < max(token) for any other acct_no for a particular customer_id.
In this case, it is the 2nd last record.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the window functions `first_value()` to calculate the maximum `token` for the biggest `acct_no` for each customer.  Then for rows that have the biggest token for each `customerid`/`acct_no` check to see if any `tokens` are larger:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             first_value(token) over (partition by customerid order by acct_no desc, token desc) as token_biggest_acct_no,
             row_number() over (partition by customerid, acct_no order by token desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1 and    -- only consider last rows for customers/accounts
      token > token_biggest_acct_no;
```